# Regex. Escape group?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way to make `something.+()[]*` matching literally 'something.+()[]*'? I'm using regex builder so manual escaping is not allowed. Sure, i can add hardcoded checks `if (char === '+') return '\+'` but i'm looking for native solution or better way

**UPD**

I'm sorry. I forgot to add that matching should be in given order with moving forward but not back. So `[+.]` will not fit my requirements because it will match both `+.` and `.+`. I need only first case (In definition order)

Comment: _new RegExp("\\+");_

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape them if within square brackets.. I just tested and works for me, but maybe not what you are looking for?

```
something[.+()[]]
```

Comment: But that way, you'll also match `something[` or `something+`.

Comment: Good point.. Trying to make the best of a bad situation here :-D. Anyway, he wants that right?

Comment: I can't answer that, as there is no character class in the given pattern.

Comment: I updated question